# struct declaration along with C++ class public methods?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how to access data in this author's class.  I don't seem to be able to access via:

```
auto c = MyClass();
c.SomeData.a;
```

```
class MyClass {
 public:

  struct SomeData {
    typedef MyClass SomeType;

    static constexpr uint32_t a;
    ...
  }

  struct SomeOtherData {
    typedef MyClass SomeType;

    static constexpr uint32_t b;
    ...
  }
```

Are all those anonymous structs different ways to view the same data like a union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SomeData` and `SomeOtherData` structs are inner types of `MyClass`, they are not non-static data fields of `MyClass`, which is why you can't access them via your `c` variable the way you are.  `MyClass` would need to declare actual member fields using those inner types, eg:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:

  struct SomeData {
    typedef MyClass SomeType;

    static constexpr uint32_t a;
    ...
  };
  SomeData sd;

  struct SomeOtherData {
    typedef MyClass SomeType;

    static constexpr uint32_t b;
    ...
  };
  SomeOtherData sod;

  ...
};
```

```cpp
MyClass c;
c.sd.a;
c.sod.a;
```

But, since the fields you are actually trying to access are `static`, just refer to them by their owning type only, you don't need a `MyClass` variable at all, eg:

```cpp
MyClass::SomeData::a;
MyClass::SomeOtherData::b;
```

And no, these inner structs are nothing like `union`s.